# Why is it that two primary states are either disjoint or quasi-equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, representation-theory

> **Def:** In a $C^*$ algebra two states $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are called:
>
> -**equivalent** if their GNS representations $\pi_{\omega_1}$ and $\pi_{\omega_2}$ are unitarily equivalent.
>
> -**quasi-equivalent** if every subrepresentation of $\pi_{\omega_1}$ has a subrepresentation that
> is equivalent to some subrepresentation of $\pi_{\omega_2}$, and vice versa;
>
> -**disjoint** if their GNS representations $\pi_{\omega_1}$ and $\pi_{\omega_2}$ don't have any unitarily equivalent subrepresentations.

> **Def:** A state $\omega$ is called **primary** (or a factor) if $\mathcal{Z}(\pi_\omega(\mathscr{A})') = \pi_\omega(\mathscr{A})' \cap \pi_\omega(\mathscr{A})'' = \mathbb{C}$

N.P. Landsman, in *Foundations of Quantum Theory From Classical Concepts to Operator Algebras* (2017) places the assertion that "**two primary states are either disjoint or quasi-equivalent**" as a corrolary of the following proposition:

> **Prop.:** For a state $\omega$, if $\omega = t\omega_1 + (1-t)\omega_2$ for some $t \in (0,1)$, then $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are disjoint if, and only if there is a projection $K \in \mathcal{Z}(\pi_\omega(\mathscr{A})) = \pi_\omega(\mathscr{A})' \cap \pi_\omega(\mathscr{A})''$ such that:
> \begin{equation}\pi_\omega{\large|}_{K\mathscr{H}_\omega}(\mathscr{A}) \,\,\,\,\,\, \simeq \pi_{\omega_1}(\mathscr{A}), \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}\pi_\omega{\large|}_{K^\perp\mathscr{H}_\omega}(\mathscr{A}) \,\,\, \simeq \pi_{\omega_1}(\mathscr{A}). \end{equation}

I don't understand why **two primary states are either disjoint or quasi-equivalent**" follows as a corollary from this proposition. If the two primary states are the same this is false, isn't it?, but considering the expression as implying that the two are distinct what impedes them from being equivalent? Let's say $\omega_1$ is primary $\mathcal{Z}(\pi_{\omega_1}(\mathscr{A})')=\mathbb{C}$ and $\omega_2$ is primary $\mathcal{Z}(\pi_{\omega_2}(\mathscr{A})')=\mathbb{C}$ and $\omega_1$ is equivalent to $\omega_2$ that is $\exists U$ unitary, $\, U\pi_{\omega_1}(a)U^* = \pi_{\omega_2}(a) \,\,,\forall a \in \mathscr{A}$ ?

Comment: I guess equivalent implies quasi-equivalent. So when Landsman says that they are either disjoint or quasi-equivalent he is not saying that they cannot also be equivalent.

Comment: But then why would this theorem imply that if they were not disjoint then they would necessarily be quasi-equivalent?